# Generalizing the notion of convexity for differentiable functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose $f$ is twice differentiable and its second derivative nonnegative in some interval $I$. We can "algebraically" characterize this by saying that $f$ satisfies, for all $t \in [0,1]$ and $x,y \in I$

$f(tx + (1-t)y) \leq tf(x) + (1-t)f(y)$. We can also observe that the graph of $f$ lies above all of its tangents.

Are there analogous "algebraic" or geometric interpretations of a nonnegative $n$th derivative? Or, indeed, even just the third derivative?

Comment: If the 3rd derivative is non negative, then the first derivative is convex, of course.

Comment: @davcha Yes, but I mean in terms of the graph of $f$, not $f'$.

Comment: Take $f'(x) = 3x^2-1$, then $f(x) = x^3-x$, what can be said about $f$ ? It is not monotonically increasing or decreasing, it is not convex nor concave. What else ?

Comment: @davcha Well, that's what I'm asking. For first derivatives, the sign of the derivative corresponds to the monotonicity of $f$, which one can algebraically describe in terms of inequalities. For second derivatives, the sign corresponds to convexity/convacity, which one can algebraically describe in terms of inequalities. Is there anything the sign of higher derivatives correspond to in purely algebraic (or geometric) terms?